PERIOD_ADD() and DATE_FORMAT() in PieCloudDB
I'm migrating from MySQL to PieCloudDB, there is a query in MySQL:
WITH base AS (
        SELECT account_id, DATE_FORMAT(day, '%Y%m') AS yearmonth
        FROM Transactions
            JOIN Accounts USING (account_id)
        WHERE type = 'Creditor'
        GROUP BY account_id, DATE_FORMAT(day, '%Y%m')
        HAVING SUM(amount) > MAX(max_income)
    )
SELECT DISTINCT account_id
FROM base
WHERE (account_id, PERIOD_ADD(yearmonth, 1)) IN (
    SELECT account_id, yearmonth
    FROM base
)

But I found that PieCloudDB does not support DATE_FORMAT() and PERIOD_ADD(), I need to find an alternative.

PERIOD_ADD(yearmonth, 1) adds 1 month to the date stored in the column. Find according function in the documentation (DATE_ADD or similar)

Please post a link to the English language version of PieCloudDB's SQL docs.  I couldn't find any at the OpenPie website.  Also, do they have GitHub project?

Well, after consulting some documents and the help of google, I learned that in PieCloudDB, TO_CHAR() can be used instead of DATE_FORMAT().
WITH base AS (
    SELECT account_id, TO_CHAR(day, 'YYYYMM') AS yearmonth
    FROM Transactions
    JOIN Accounts USING (account_id)
    WHERE type = 'Creditor'
    GROUP BY account_id, TO_CHAR(day, 'YYYYMM')
    HAVING SUM(amount) > MAX(max_income)
)
SELECT DISTINCT account_id
FROM base
WHERE (account_id, TO_CHAR((yearmonth||'01')::date + interval '1 month', 'YYYYMM')) IN (
    SELECT account_id, yearmonth
    FROM base
);


You are right, I'll correct it, thanks for your approach. @user1191247
